# Trouble correctly adding numbers in a python program

Tags: python

I am trying to simulate dice being rolled. Die_1 + Die_2 five times. The program runs, but the math is wrong. I have tried this multiple ways, but cannot get the math correct. The die are only being rolled one at a time, so a 1 and a six are possibilities. It must be an overly tired oversight. Any ideas would be fantastic. Code and output below. Thank you to anyone who can help.

```
# This program will simulate dice rolls 5 different
# times and add the total of each roll.
import random
import math
MIN = 1
MAX = 6
ROLLS = 5

def main():
    for count in range(ROLLS):
        die_1 = (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        die_2 = (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        combined_roll = point(die_1, die_2)
        print('Here are the combined rolls for the dice!')
        print(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        print(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        print('The combined roll is:', combined_roll)

def point(die_1, die_2):
    roll_1 = die_1 + die_2

    combined_roll = roll_1 
    return combined_roll
main()

Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
4
3
The combined roll is: 4
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
2
2
The combined roll is: 7
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
5
4
The combined roll is: 5
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
3
5
The combined roll is: 9
Here are the combined rolls for the dice!
3
1
The combined roll is: 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math and everything is correct. It is indeed a symptom of being tired.

You're printing out entirely new numbers in these 2 lines:

```
print(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
print(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
```

Compared to what your die rolls actually were, earlier in time.

```
die_1 = (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
die_2 = (random.randint(MIN, MAX))
```

Time has passed so your random number generation is going to be in a different state.

So change the prints to:

```
print(die_1)
print(die_2)
```

Comment: @user3758480 EugeneK is right, you are repeating the same error in another question. Having a sleep could be the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

This is best achieved with a simple function and `random.randint`:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> def roll_dice(n=1):
...     return [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]
...
```

1-die roll:

```
>>> roll_dice()
[2]
>>> roll_dice()
[2]
>>> roll_dice()
[5]
```

2-die roll:

```
>>> roll_dice(2)
[6, 2]
>>> roll_dice(2)
[6, 2]
>>> roll_dice(2)
[5, 5]
>>>
```

You can easily sum a 2-die roll by:

```
>>> sum(roll_dice(2))
6
>>> sum(roll_dice(2))
7
>>> sum(roll_dice(2))
8
```

Answer (score 0):

The second set if print statements mean to print die_1 and die_2, nit calls to random again. If you call random again, you get new random numbers.